# Through VB script I am unable to get formatting of cells controlled by Data validation

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am trying to get value and background color of the cell on which data validation is set. 
When a wrong value from drop down is selected, the cell/Drop down bg-color changes to red. This in need to capture in another excel for all combinations of drop downs/Cell values.

I am using VB script to set values in excel cells on which data validation is set and using the same script I try to extract the set value along with it's formatting.

```
obj_Exl_WS_input.Cells(in_row,in_col).Copy
obj_Exl_WS_output.Cells(out_row,out_col).PasteSpecial -4122
obj_Exl_WS_output.Cells(out_row,out_col).PasteSpecial -4163
```

Expected outcome: Value from the selected cell along with it's back-groung color should be pasted in output excel.

Actual outcome: Only value of the cell is pasted in output excel not he back-ground or font color.

[Note: Code is in .vbs file]

Comment: two ways I can think of. **[1.]** Copy the cell with all it's formattinga and CF rules. In that case use `-4104` instead of `-4122` or `-4163` **[2.]** Check if the CF rule is true or not and then color the cell based on that. **[Note]** I am sure there could be more ways of doing it but while "on the road (posting from phone)" I could only think of these 2 possibilities...

Comment: Hi Siddhartha, I did what you suggested and -4104 copies data validation into the specified cell, rather I wish only to have color and value of source cell to destination cell and not data validation setup.

Comment: Yes that is what it will do. If you are ok with it copying the conditional formatting then we can simple delete the data validation after the copy paste.

Comment: Well I was able to solve my problem using code.  obj_Exl_WS_output.Cells(out_row,out_col).Interior.ColorIndex = Cint(obj_Exl_WS_input.Cells(in_row,in_col).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex)<br/> As my requeirment was only to copy the cell color. Here in my scenario I have millions of records and it would be tedious task to delete validations. <br/> As my input and output excels are different -4104 some how did not work for me.  I really appreciate your inputs which gave me hints in which direction I need to look out for answers. @SiddharthRout Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to solve my problem using code. 
    `obj_Exl_WS_output.Cells(out_row,out_col).Interior.ColorIndex =Cint(obj_Exl_WS_input.Cells(in_row,in_col).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex)`

As my input and output excels are different -4104 some how did not work for me.